# Для чего нужен Switch react-router-dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Видел, что есть

```
<Router> 
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/'> <Home /> </Route>
        <Route exact path='/about'> <About /> </Route>
        <Route exact path='/contact'> <Contact /> </Route>
    </Switch>
</Router>
```

А есть

```
<Router> 
        <Route exact path='/'> <Home /> </Route>
        <Route exact path='/about'> <About /> </Route>
        <Route exact path='/contact'> <Contact /> </Route>
</Router>
```

Можете, пожалуйста, объяснить в каких случаях нужно использовать Switch и для чего он служит?

Comment: https://reactrouter.com/core/api/Switch в справке есть пример

Answer (score 2):

В общем случае, он позволяет выбрать первый попавшийся маршрут который соответствует текущему `pathname`.

Например у нас есть 2 роута:

```
<Route path="/about" .../>
<Route path="/:id" .../>
```

маршрут `/about` соответствует и первому и второму маршруту. Для того чтобы в приложении не отобразились обе компоненты соответствующие этим маршрутам, нужно обернуть из в `Switch`

```
<Switch>
    <Route path="/about" .../>
    <Route path="/:id" .../>
</Switch>
```